# Windows 7 network, deploy portable devices

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers

We are planning to roll out Windows 7 in a school and are wondering if this can solve some ongoing issues that we have always experienced with XP.

Server 2008 R2
Clients Windows 7 32-bit

The school uses a bunch of devices on ad-hoc basis, things like Scanners, Lego Robots and digital microscopes. All these devices travel around the school and can be plugged into any PC on site. Previously we had to install everything manually and were hoping that there is a feature under windows 7 that would allow a user to install the device without admin rights.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you preinstall the drivers on each machine, you won't need admin privs.

The reason why this is an admin priv is because drivers pass data at the kernel level, thus making it potential avenue for malware.  A well written virus installed as a driver will defeat all the mainstream anti-virus products out there.